# Can I avoid distorted circles at high zoom levels in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm making a garden planning app. I'd like to use satellite imagery for context, thus the choice of Leaflet. Now I'd like to plot out individual plant locations with circles around each plant to show the recommended planting radii. Compared to the typical features displayed by Leaflet these circles are very small, on the order of 0.1m radii or even smaller. I'm finding that circles render distorted at these small sizes, and that the direction of the distortion changes varies with the circle's location. Here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/d2ncr6vq/1/

```
L.circle([-33.865002, 151.2094], {radius: 0.1}).addTo(map);
L.circle([-33.865004, 151.2094], {radius: 0.1}).addTo(map);
L.circle([-33.865006, 151.2094], {radius: 0.1}).addTo(map);
L.circle([-33.865008, 151.2094], {radius: 0.1}).addTo(map);
```

and a screenshot

[image: nested circles, smallest distorted]

Is this a sign that I should be using a different tool to draw at these small sizes, or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are those coords decimal degrees? Likely. If decimal degrees I'd say you are dealing with not enough precision in their range. Or you are dealing with enough precision: But the radius cannot not know what the diameters are (recursively) on circles so drawn, hence the overlap. .......... You could do some math to figure out what the radii should be "visually" for no overlap in rendering. But that would be a lot.

Comment: @GetSet Ah. Sorry for the confusion. I'm not concerned about the overlap, only the aspect ratio, which should be roughly 1:1. I lined up several circles only to demonstrate the variation in aspect ratio.

Answer (score 3):

This is a side effect of the geodetic approximation of circles to ellipses since [#2345](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/2345), and floating point arithmetic. Internally, Leaflet unprojects and reprojects the circle's center and topmost point to calculate the aspect ratio of the ellipses, and with such a small radius and non-trivial math being performed, the code is hitting the precision limits of [floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic). The errors you see are, in fact, rounding errors.

The only approach to this is to work with (projected) coordinates closer to the (projected) origin of coordinates. Consider using a custom (local) [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) for this task.

Comment: Cool. That makes sense to me in theory but I'm not sure how to implement this in Leaflet. Do I set the map's CRS to something custom and local? If that's the approach, shouldn't drawing at (0,0) in the default CRS also give non-distorted circles? I tried, but got the same distorted results. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Might I ping you (or others) again for more detail here? This definitely makes sense as the way forward, but I'm not quite sure how to do this in Leaflet (See above comment). Here's a fiddle that I think should work if I understand you correctly, but doesn't: https://jsfiddle.net/2wjfs15y/

Answer (score -1):

I think you just want a circle with out distorted.you can try ‘CircleMarker’ in Leaflet ,and it's radius unit is in pixels

Comment: Unfortunately the circles have real-world radii so I need them to scale with the map when zooming. Otherwise yes, circle markers would be great!